# Draw an elliptical cross-section of right circular cone onto the unfolded cone

Tags: geometry, contest-math, conic-sections, solid-geometry

If I know the dimensions of a right circular cone (base radius, height and slant height; and place an elliptical cross section inside the cone; how do I get the equations for the original ellipse and what does it look like in the cone's UNFOLDED plane diagram?

Problem: A right circular cone stands on a horizontal base of radius $r$. Its vertex $V$ is a distance $k$ from each point on the perimeter of the base. The plane section of a cone is an ellipse with lowest point $L$ and highest point $H$. On the curved surface of the cone, to one side of plane $VLH$, two routes $R_1$ and $R_2$, from $L$ to $H$ are marked; $R_1$ follows the semi-perimeter of the ellipse, while $R_2$ is the route of shortest length. Find the condition that $R_1$ and $R_2$ intersect between $L$ and $H$.
(No answer online. From 1975 British Math Olympiad; problem 5).

I really want to go from an ellipse as the plane section mentioned drawn on a right circular cone to unravelling it into its plane net - to "see" if the $R_1$ and $R_2$ actually intersect. Will this occur for a "narrow / tall" cone or a "wide ' short" cone?

Comment: Please provide a figure...

Comment: You might be interested by [this reference](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1633435/FULLTEXT02).

Comment: I constructed ellipse and geodetic with  GeoGebra: looks like they intersect if height/radius>3. Here it is: https://www.geogebra.org/m/na5wsbh5

Comment: Being a Math Olimpiad problem I expect a fairly simple solution to exist, but don't see any at the moment.

Comment: Jean Marie - nice article and the GeoGebra Intelligent pauca - I am novice in these tools and retired now - 10 years.  But I love the cone problems!  Thank you both

Comment: @Intelligenci pauca Very nice. Is it possible to see your code for that ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Click on the three dots up-right on that page and choose Details: on the new page you can download the source.

Comment: @Intelligenci pauca Thank you very much. I didn't know this possibility.

Comment: This paper could also be of interest: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/apostol388.pdf

Comment: Thanks Intelligent pauca - ordered the copy of the paper on rolling out a cone.  I need to see basics of cone equation and plane intersecting it.... I am amazed at the math talent around the World behind the Math Stackexchange site! Ron

Comment: Can the author of the first solution re-insert the solution of equations of cone and intersecting plane?  Somehow it was deleted  - or does not appear?  Please - Thanks!  Ron

Comment: Intelligenti pauca - would you recall the way gasheem developed equation of cutting plane of the cone?  He had nx*x + nz*(z-zo) = 0.  Where did this get developed?  How are nx, nz and z0 selected? where does the cutting plane start and end?  Does it start at the LEFT base of the cone and climb upward to the right? Does it need to start fro the base?  I realize it was in the first answer but it no longer appears here - not sure why?   Ron

Comment: That plane was determined by the values of $n_x$, $n_y$ and $z_0$. But if you are interested in how to write the equation of the ellipse when unfolded, you can look at  eq. 23 on page 405 of that paper I linked above, with the explanation that follows.

Comment: Intelligenti pauca - I got a copy of the paper from printery here. Thanks. Is this what you programmed in GeoGebra to get the 3 figures? What equations did you use to see the intersection case?  Are you really in Italy?  Ron in Manchester NH.

Comment: In GeoGebra I didn't write any equation: I constructed a cone and a plane crossing it, then their intersection (an ellipse). I placed a point $P$ on the ellipse, then constructed a point $Q$ on $xy$ plane having distance $VP$ from the origin and making an angle $\beta=(r/k)\phi$ with $x$ axis. Finally, I constructed the locus of $Q$ using the "locus" tool. Yes, I'm in Rome.

Comment: But to answer the Olympiad problem it isn't necessary to have the equation of the unfolded ellipse, some reasoning is enough (as I explained in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

As it was to be expected from a Math Olympiad problem, there is a fairly simple solution to this question.

The semi-ellipse $R_1$ (blue in the unfolded cone represented below) forms a right angle with generatrices $VL$ and $VH$, at points $L$ and $H$ (this is obvious if you consider the 3D setting). Consider now the angles formed by the geodesic $R_2$ with the same generatrices at $L$ and $H$: they can be better visualised on the unfolded surface of the cone, where the geodesic is a straight line (red in figure below). We always have $\angle VLH<90°$, because $VL>VH$. On the contrary, $\angle VHL$ can be acute but also obtuse.

But if $\angle VHL>90°$, then the geodesic joins the ellipse at $H$ "from below", implying an intersection between the curves. The limiting case is $\angle VHL=90°$, which is attained for $VH=VL\cos\beta$ (see figure).

But $\beta k=\pi r$, because the length of the circular arc in the unfolded figure is the same as the perimeter of the base of the cone. Hence the curves intersect if:
$$
{VH\over VL}<\cos{\pi r\over k}.
$$

[image]

EDIT.

To help understanding, here are two figures representing the other two cases: $\angle VHL<90°$ (left) and $\angle VHL>90°$ (right), with the curves intersecting in the latter. All figures were made with GeoGebra Classic 5.

[image]

Comment: The above CRITERION is what I was looking for in the problem's statement. Excellent!  I have a lot to learn and review.  In the s equation in the above answer does anyone know nx, nz, and zo values to use to plot the ellipse? Is this in polar coordinates - as on an xy grid?

Comment: @RonaldYannone $n_x$, $n_y$ and $z_0$ are generic numbers in the equation of the plane where the ellipse lies. But you should ask ghasheem about that.

Comment: ghasheem  - can you re-insert your solution in here too? It disappeared. Can you help with the nx, nz and zo to use in your formula?  Thanks.   Ron

Comment: Intelligenti pauca - sorry to bother you.  Can you possibly send or insert the GeoGebra code to generate the intersecting example here you did?  What parameter used as variable - that I can try different cases with?  Would really appreciate it.   Ron in Manchester NH

Comment: @RonaldYannone I uploaded it here: https://geogebra.org/m/na5wsbh5 updating the one I had already shared. See my comment above to download the source file.